# Does the C programming language have a runtime?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, runtime

Objective-C has a runtime that translates its syntax into functions that are organized and compiled. Does C have a runtime library? Also, if anyone can answer the question, what are the steps GCC takes during C compilation? e.g. main.c >> main.s >> main.bin

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_runtime

Comment: Microsoft calls it a runtime. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You seem to be unclear on what a runtime system does. It does not "translate [...] syntax into functions"; that's the compiler's job. The runtime in ObjC primarily provides the object infrastructure: creation of classes, sending of messages, and so forth. (There are other pieces to it, of course.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, the C language features a standard library; that is, a number of standard macros, routines and types one can use in his programs, apart from any in the core language itself.

In popular implementations, there is a separate library file containing the code for the C standard library. For example, in GNU/Linux environments, the GNU C library (`libc`) is almost always present. Microsoft provides the `msvcrt.dll` runtime library for the Windows system, and so on.

Also, the C standard library might not be available in freestanding implementations. Sometimes it is possible to compile a program without linking against the C standard library from your system. As an example, the Windows API is well known for behaving as a freestanding C programming environment (although one might need to link against other system libraries specific to Windows).

Regarding GCC, the following illustrates briefly the compilation pipeline:

1. The input source is preprocessed with GNU `cpp`, resulting in a translation unit. *(Actually, as Basile pointed out, nowadays no `cpp` process is created; the entire preprocessing work is done within `cc1`. Nevertheless, the resulting behavior is most likely the same as with `cpp`.)*
2. The translation unit is then interpreted and compiled to assembly source with GCC `cc1`;
3. The assembly source is then assembled into object code with GNU `as`;
4. Finally, object files and libraries are linked together to produce a binary image with GNU `ld`.

Naturally, each of these steps may be altered or not executed at all depending on the driver options; the above is just a rough explanation of the overall process.

Comment: This is wrong today: with recent GCC (even GCC from the early 2000s), the preprocessing and compilation is done by `cc1` and there is no more any `cpp` process

Answer (score 6):

C has a standard library (`libc` on Linux, which provides standard functions like those in `<stdio.h>` such as `fprintf` and in `<stdlib.h>` such as `malloc` and also all the system calls), and even when you use `gcc` in free standing mode with `gcc -ffreestanding` (e.g. to compile a `libc` or some kernel) it links a tiny `libgcc` library which provides the functionality built-in the language (e.g. 64 bits addition on 32 bits platforms).

To learn what the `gcc` command is doing, pass it the `-v` flag. (Don't forget to take the habit to always compile with `-Wall` to get warnings and `-g` to get the debug information), e.g.

```
 % gcc -v -g -Wall hello.c -o hello
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 4.7.2-4' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,go,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.7 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.7 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --with-arch-32=i586 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-4) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-g' '-Wall' '-o' 'hello' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/cc1 -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu hello.c -quiet -dumpbase hello.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase hello -g -Wall -version -o /tmp/ccsWt3UC.s
GNU C (Debian 4.7.2-4) version 4.7.2 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.7.2, GMP version 5.0.5, MPFR version 3.1.0-p10, MPC version 0.9
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C (Debian 4.7.2-4) version 4.7.2 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.7.2, GMP version 5.0.5, MPFR version 3.1.0-p10, MPC version 0.9
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: c5f63dedeacd449634699df94fe3d914
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-g' '-Wall' '-o' 'hello' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 as -v --64 -o /tmp/ccO5i3pU.o /tmp/ccsWt3UC.s
GNU assembler version 2.22 (x86_64-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.22
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-g' '-Wall' '-o' 'hello' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/collect2 --sysroot=/ --build-id --no-add-needed --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=both -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o hello /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../.. /tmp/ccO5i3pU.o -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
```

Notice that [collect2](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Collect2.html) is the linker wrapped to do additional things, and that `libc.so` gets used by almost every Linux executable (because it is wrapping [syscalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syscall)).

Answer (score 2):

C has a standard library (e.g., `strlen`, `malloc`, etc.)

The steps are: compile your code that uses the standard library, then link your code to the standard library. `libc` can be contained in either a static library or a dynamic library, depending; usually both are available.